# Usage of for_each in the presence of exceptions? std::exception_list

Tags: c++, exception, foreach, c++17, stl-algorithm

cppreference documentation https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each
says that:

> - If execution of a function invoked as part of the algorithm throws an exception and ExecutionPolicy is one of the **three standard policies**, **std::terminate is called**. For any other ExecutionPolicy, the behavior is implementation-defined.

I interpret that this means that I cannot, out-of-the-box, throw from the `for_each` passed function and expect to catch the excetion or some information related to it.

The reason I was expecting to use exceptions was so that I could partially undo (revert) the changes made in the `for_each` call.
(Maybe there is a better algorithm for that).

However, just by chance I found a historical version of `for_each` which is documented to have a different, more interesting behavior:

http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/C.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/output/en/cpp/algorithm/for_each.html

> - if policy is std::parallel_vector_execution_policy, std::terminate is called
> - if policy is std::sequential_execution_policy or std::parallel_execution_policy, **the algorithm exits with an std::exception_list containing all uncaught exceptions**. If there was only one uncaught exception, the algorithm may rethrow it without wrapping in std::exception_list. It is unspecified how much work the algorithm will perform before returning after the first exception was encountered.

Which seems to imply that instead of `terminate`ing, there is the possibility of actually using exceptions.

**So, why `std::exception_list` was eliminated?, was it too controversial, too complicated, too (memory) costly?**

Even if I agree with the logic, I really don't have any other option because parallel `for_each` returns `void` (instead of the UnaryFunction back, which is also surprising).
Therefore,
this `std::exception_list` protocol seem to me in a necessary component to undo a failed-to-complete `for_each` instruction.

Is it reasonable to expect that some new custom policy, e.g. `par_with_failed_list` will appear somewhere allowing for `undo`ing.

---

**More context**: This pattern of undoing a failed loop is used in construction of containers. I want to implement a custom (parallel/sequencial) `uninitialized_value_construct_n` which "undo's" (destroy) the initilized objects when (any of the unsequenced) constructions fail.

---

**EDIT1**: On a second though, it might be possible to pass a captured variable in the lambda to a function parameter. 
This variable could be a shared concurrent data that can store the exceptions as they happen (as a exception_list). 
I wonder if this has been done already.

---

**EDIT2**: I found an implementation of `exception_list` in HPX,
https://github.com/STEllAR-GROUP/hpx/blob/master/hpx/exception_list.hpp
https://github.com/STEllAR-GROUP/hpx/blob/master/src/exception_list.cpp

Comment: That was [p0394r4](http://wg21.link/p0394r4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::exception_list` added a lot of complexity to the specification and implementation of parallel algorithms without much corresponding gain.

As a user, you can handle this case in the functor:

```
struct exception_info{
    ElementType* element;
    std::exception_ptr exception;
};
std::vector<exception_info> exceptions;
std::mutex exceptions_mutex;

std::vector<ElementType> range=...;

std::for_each(std::execution::par,range.begin(),range.end(),[&](ElementType& element){
    try{ do_stuff(element); }
    catch(...){
        std::lock_guard guard(exceptions_mutex);
        exceptions.push_back({&element,std::current_exception()});
    }});
```

The `exceptions` list will now contain a list of pointers to the elements where an exception was thrown and the thrown exceptions.

Comment: Fantastic, I was trying to simulate `exception_list` but this is much more straight forward. I guess the simple decision of whether to use a linked list or an array to store the exception is enough to open a can of worms. Perhaps those decision cab be part of the execution policy (`for_each(std::execution::par_guarded(exceptions_vector/list)`). Aside, the interesting thing about this type of exceptions in my context is that they have to have enough information to undo the action that provoked it.

Comment: I am now curious: If I understand correctly, `current_exception` returns a non-owning pointer-like to the current exception. By the time I have access to the `exceptions`-vector (after the `for_each`), how is it possible that all the different exceptions are still alive (not destroyed)? isn't `exceptions` in the code just an array of dangling pointers at the end?

Comment: `std::current_exception()` returns a `std::exception_ptr`, which is an *owning* pointer. The pointer either keeps the original exception alive until the pointer is destroyed, or keeps enough information to rethrow a copy of the exception when asked.

Comment: Ah, missed the “owning part” from the doc. Am I correct that it is like a share_ptr (with its own counting and lock?) and that the only operation one can do with it is to rethrow (a copy?)?

Comment: Yes, it's likely to be reference counted like a `shared_ptr`. The only thing you can do other than copy the pointer is call `rethrow_exception`, which may throw the original or a copy.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I understand why this was not standardized. This seems really brute force: there are locks everywhere, one for each element and one for the container (of exceptions). On top of that, if multiple types of exceptions happen one should have extra facilities such as rethrowing a "common/reduced" exception . An even worst, the logic on how to undo anything would be daunting. (For context I originally wanted this to have a parallel `uninitialized_copy_construct`). **Someone should write a book about all this ;)**. (BTW, I own the *first edition* of your great C++ Concurrency book).